# Searching for a recent question: Why do we see distinct objects?

Tags: discussion

Could someone help me find the post of the person who wondered why, with all the light rays bouncing off of multiple objects and crossing in complex ways, do we see distinct objects instead of a light "blur" of some sort. He put a drawing in that showed many light lines crossing and said that was how he construed what our eye should be seeing.

I'm a neuroscientist with a strong interest in physics. I have an answer for him but I cannot find the original question. Could someone help please?

Comment: In response to a comment which has since vanished: I think that questions of the form “I know this post exists, and I have searched for it, and I cannot find it” are perfectly reasonable for meta. If there are ever too many of them, we can discuss that.

Comment: Could be this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/712613/83835

Answer (score 4):

Is [this it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713354/179151)?

Note that we do have a [search feature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching). It might help to tell us what you tried doing to search for this on your own so we know how to help users in the future find certain questions they are looking for.